# Try-except doesn't work as intended (failing my try on purpes but it doesnt do the except)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, try-except, seleniumbase

I have this code:

```py
            try:
                self.send_keys(fn.FieldsNames.event_html, fn.FieldsNames.position_change)
                self.click(f"//*[contains(text(),'{fn.FieldsNames.position_change}')]")
                f.Functions.wait_for_loading(self)
                self.send_keys(fn.FieldsNames.event_reason_html_job_info, fn.FieldsNames.department_change)
                self.click(f"//*[contains(text(),'{fn.FieldsNames.department_change}')]")
                self.clear(fn.FieldsNames.department_html)
                self.send_keys(fn.FieldsNames.department_html, "random_department")
                self.sleep(2)
                self.click(f"//*[contains(text(),'{random_department}')]")
                f.Functions.wait_for_loading(self)
                old_department = self.get_text(fn.FieldsNames.old_department_value_html)
                self.click(f"//*[contains(text(),'{fn.FieldsNames.save}')]")
                self.wait_for_element_absent(f"//*[contains(text(),'{fn.FieldsNames.save}')]")
                self.refresh()
            except:
                self.refresh()
            else:
                self.refresh()
```

and I fail on purpes this line

`self.send_keys(fn.FieldsNames.department_html, random_department)`

instead of random_department I wrote "fail test" but my code doesn't fail (or raising exception) so it kinda passes above the except and continues to run the code. what could be the problem? Can you give me suggestions on how to write this code more efficiently.

Comment: Why would it fail? You've caught the exception and suppressed it, instead using `refresh()`

Comment: Your `except:` catches and hides all exceptions. You might want to narrow that down to specific exceptions and/or do `except Exceptions as e:` then use `e` to print or reraise the exception.

Comment: I dont understand. When I have something in try for example a line with click on button with spesific element and it doesnt find it, it should go directly to except no?

Comment: What I need to do if I want when my code fails inside a try to refresh the website?

Comment: Can you say why changing the text string `"random_department"` to the text string `"fail_test"` would cause an exception in `send_keys`?

Comment: It will because the code then will not find this line                 self.click(f"//*[contains(text(),'{random_department}')]")
This is why I expecting my code to fail and then go to except. I dont understand what Im doing wrong?

Comment: OK. How do you know it doesn't go to the `except`?

Comment: Because I see on the screen it doesnt refresh the website. I dont know how to make it work I tried everything.

Comment: If you remove the `try...except...` but keep the code otherwise the same, what exception message do you get?